# How to specify “partition (partx)” in “mysqldump” command?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, mysqldump

I have to export some data from a table which is partitioned, and with some extra condition
So I use `mysqldump` command,and use `--where"xxxxxx"` options as below

```
mysqldump -hxxx -Pxxx -uxxx xxx rtm --tables xxx --where="xxx"> xxx
```

But how can I specify `partition (partx)` keyword in `mysqldump` command，since I just need the data from the specific partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plan A:  Provide a `WHERE` clause that exactly covers that partition.

Plan B:  Let's discuss (1) why you are using partitioning, and (2) why you need that kind of dump.

Plan C:  See "transportable tablespaces" as a way to break off a partition, turning it into an independent table.

Comment: Maybe planA is good for me.